# NodeJS / Multer : How to replace exising file in directory with new file

Tags: node.js, file, directory, upload, multer

I want to replace existing file in directory when upload new new , I'm using nodeJS and multer, the idea is to read directory content, delete it and then upload the new file.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const authorize = require('_middleware/authorize')
const Role = require('_helpers/role')
const uploadImage = require("./uploadAdvertising")
const fs = require('fs')
const uploadDir = '/public/advertising/'

// routes
router.post('/', authorize(Role.Admin), uploadImage, createAdvertising);

module.exports = router;

async function createAdvertising(req, res, next) {
    fs.readdir(global.__basedir + uploadDir, ((err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err
        for (const file of files){
            fs.unlink(global.__basedir + uploadDir + file, err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
    }))
    if (!req.file) return res.status(412).send({
        message: `image is required`,
    });
    uploadImage(req, res)
        .then(data => {

            return res.status(201).send({
                message: 'Advertising image saved'
            })
        }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file, ${err}`,
        });
    })
}
```

**multer**

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");
const maxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
const uploadDir = '/public/advertising/'
const fs = require('fs')
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, global.__basedir + uploadDir)
        req.uploadDirectory = global.__basedir + uploadDir
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    },
});

let uploadImage = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        //reject
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
            cb(null, true)
        } else {
            cb(new Error("image should be png or jpeg extension"), false)
        }
    },
    limits: {fileSize: maxSize},
}).single("imageAdvertising");

let uploadFileMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadImage);
module.exports = uploadFileMiddleware;
```

can some one take a look and tell what's wrong with this code ! it delete all content even the new uploaded file !

Answer (score 0):

just try like this in the multer file

note : write the path of uploaded file in `unlinkSync` and `readdirSync`

```
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    let files = fs.readdirSync('write the path');
    if(files.includes(file.originalname)){
        fs.unlinkSync('pwrite the pathath'+ file.originalname);
    }
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(new Error("image should be png or jpeg extension"), false)
    }
}
```

and remove extra code like `createAdvertising` file